# Was a copy of Bobadilla's lost report on Christopher Columbus found in a Spanish archive in 2006?

Tags: christopher-columbus, document-authenticity

As claimed in [The Guardian](http://www.theguardian.com/world/2006/aug/07/books.spain).

A transcription of the document is apparently available on JSTOR [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/j.ctt6wptvz), the section "Pesquisa Del Comendador Francisco de Bobadilla".

Has the document been confirmed as genuine?

Answer (score 2):

The document was found in 2005 by archivist Isabel Aguirre in the General Archive of Simancas. So far, nobody has disputed its authenticity and a renown expert on Columbus, Consuelo Varela, published a book and several scientific publications on it.

TL;DR; **Yes, the document is deemed authentic.**

*Disclaimer*: the document being authentic and the events presented in it being true are, of course, two different things. The document was used in the trial against Columbus, and it was written by the main prosecutor of the case, Francisco de Bobadilla.

You can have a look at the book Varela & Aguirre wrote about this document and the general cause against Columbus [here](https://books.google.es/books?id=SwtMUtesSDEC&pg=PA178&lpg=PA178&dq=isabel%20aguirre%20simancas%20bobadilla&source=bl&ots=qUMujUM0DK&sig=ACfU3U3t7UBqXty7zRrpQnbLS9o3CX-GxQ&hl=es&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi4lKrN6-jpAhVD3IUKHR0WBYIQ6AEwAHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=isabel%20aguirre%20simancas%20bobadilla&f=false)

Comment: Please [provide some references](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/5) to support your claims. (I know this is old. I was just checking why an upvoted user would post an answer with no references, and found this.)

Comment: I wasn't able to found it but there is a web page in Simancas's General Archives with a database of documents:
https://www.culturaydeporte.gob.es/cultura/areas/archivos/mc/archivos/ags/bases-de-datos.html